# Pasar fecha a funcion en php

Tags: php, funciones

Estoy haciendo un script en php que a través de una fecha de pago me da el próximo vencimiento teniendo en cuenta el estado, o sea, si esta pago o no. Algo asi:

```
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE useride = '".$code."' AND estado = 0");
$fila = $list->fetch();
$mes = '+30 day';
$sem = '+180 day';
$anu = '+365 day';
$periodo = $fila['periodo'];

if ($periodo == 'mensual') {
$fecha = $fila['fechapago'];
$nfecha = strtotime ($mes , strtotime ($fecha)) ;
$nfecha = date ('d-m-Y' , $nfecha);
echo $nfecha;

} elseif ($periodo == 'semestral') {
$fecha = $fila['fechapago'];
$nfecha = strtotime ($sem , strtotime ($fecha)) ;
$nfecha = date ('d-m-Y' , $nfecha);
echo $nfecha;

} else {
$fecha = $fila['fechapago'];
$nfecha = strtotime ($anu , strtotime ($fecha)) ;
$nfecha = date ('d-m-Y' , $nfecha);
echo $nfecha;
}
```

Mi idea es pasarlo a una funcion y la verdad, no se usar bien las funciones o mejor dicho, no se crearlas. No espero que lo hagan pero si me orienten un poco. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En términos generales las funciones necesitan recibir en parámetro todos aquellos valores con los que van a trabajar... o ningún parámetro si todo lo necesario está dentro del ámbito de la función. Y, si es preciso, devolverán el valor esperado.

En este caso, asumimos que al menos el valor `$fila` es obtenido fuera de la función. Luego lo pasamos en parámetro para que la función trabaje con esa información. Fíjate que he creado un valor `$calculo`, que cambiará según el valor de `$periodo` y al final de los  `if`, hacemos el cálculo con el valor que corresponda. Así, nos ahorramos varias líneas de código, ganando en simplicidad y claridad en el programa... Finalmente, devolverá (`return`), los datos finales.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*
    *Vamos a suponer que la consulta se hace desde otra parte
    *Aunque puedes hacer esto dentro de la función,
    *todo dependerá de tu conexto
*/
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE useride = '".$code."' AND estado = 0");
$fila = $list->fetch();

/*
    *Ahora le pasas $fila a la función
    *como es una función que tiene un return, puedes asignar el resultado
    *de la llamada de la función a una variable
*/

$fechaVencimiento=getVencimiento($fila);

echo $fechaVencimiento;

/*
    *Esta es la función y el parámetro que recibe
*/

function getVencimiento($fila){

    $periodo = $fila['periodo'];

    if ($periodo == 'mensual') {
        $calculo='+30 day';

    } elseif ($periodo == 'semestral') {
        $calculo = '+180 day';

    } else {
        $calculo = '+365 day';
    }
        $fecha = $fila['fechapago'];
        $nfecha = strtotime ($calculo , strtotime ($fecha)) ;
        $nfecha = date ('d-m-Y' , $nfecha);

/*
    *Como verás, he quitado todos los echo
    *porque interesa que la función retorne el valor sólo al final
*/
return $nfecha;

}
```

### Una forma más elegante

En algunos casos, el código queda más claro y elegante si usamos un bloque **[`switch`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)**.  El caso que expones es perfecto para usarlo. La función quedaría así:

```
function getVencimiento($fila){

    $periodo = $fila['periodo'];    

    switch ($periodo) {
        case 'mensual':
            $calculo='+30 day';
            break;

        case 'semestral':
            $calculo = '+180 day';
            break;

        default:
            $calculo = '+365 day';
    }   

    $fecha = $fila['fechapago'];
    $nfecha = strtotime ($calculo , strtotime ($fecha)) ;
    $nfecha = date ('d-m-Y' , $nfecha);

return $nfecha;

}
```

---

> **NOTA IMPORTANTE SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> La consulta `SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE useride = '".$code."' AND
>   estado = 0` es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Para corregir ese grave
>   problema de seguridad, deberías implementar el uso de consultas
>   preparadas. Para más información puedes leer:
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)

Comment: **Gracias** A. Cedano. Leí tu respuesta y gracias nuevamente, ahora entendi mas y mejor sobre el tema, sos muy amable. Lo que no sabia es que las "consultas" también son vulnerables, asi que voy a leer el articulo que me pasaste en el link. Gracias nuevamente!